# Android: Specify full method path in android:onClick

Tags: android, android-studio

This question is about Android development. In general, how do you tie a layout XML file to a certain Activity java file? This is relevant in a case such as a button with the android:onClick attribute specified. Suppose you have a layout XML file with a button like the following:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

So when this button is clicked, a `sendMessage(View view)` method is called. If more than one Activity has a `sendMessage(View view)` method, how does Android decide which one to call? There's literally absolutely nothing associating layout files with Activity files. In Android Studio, I've found that the `android:onClick="sendMessage"` defaults to the main activity's `sendMessage` method if there is more than one choice. I've also found that Android Studio doesn't let you simply specify the full method path (for example, `android:onClick="com.example.Activity2.sendMessage"`). Am I missing something?

**Edit**: I would like to add that Android Studio shows the sendMessage defaulting to a specific activity, REGARDLESS of which Activities have specified the layout via setContentView()

Comment: Android decide which method will call because you call setContentView(int layoutId) into your onCreate activity method.

Comment: "There's literally absolutely nothing associating layout files with Activity files" -- `setContentView()` has been around and documented since at least 2008. Other techniques exist (e.g., using fragments) as well.

Comment: But when I am typing the `sendMessage` in `android:onClick="sendMessage"` Android Studio shows a small popup showing "com.example.MyApp.MainActivity" REGARDLESS of what Activities have set that particular layout as their content view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android:onClick` will call the method on the `Activity` your layout is inflated and attached to. There should be no tight coupling between a layout and it's controller, so thats why you can't specify a "full path".

I'd recommend using a programatical `OnClickListener` instead of the xml attribute. It gives you much greater control.

Comment: You say there should be no tight coupling... Why does Android Studio show a small popup showing a complete method path whenever you are typing `android:onClick="......"`? I ask this mainly out of frustration, because I'm beginning to think Android Studio is simply displaying inaccurate information in an effort to be a super-extra-handy code editor.

Comment: How would that be inaccurate information? Not coupling methods to layout onClick tags is just a best practice.

Comment: It's inaccurate because, according to what has been said here, a layout is not bound to any specific activity at all by default. It gets bound to whatever Activity calls setContentView on it. So Android Studio is just confusing people by showing that small popup (`com.whatever.AppName.ActivityName`) as you're typing the method name in the layout XML file, because that's not necessarily the Activity whose method will be called.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`tools:context`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes#TOC-tools:context) attribute that you can use to tell Android Studio in what context the layout is meant to be used. You specify a class there and then it should take this class to find the correct method

But this attribute is only for the IDE. During Runtime it binds to the method of the activity that inflated the layout.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking too, but I've found that the tools:context attribute has no effect on the issue (Android Studio still claims it's defaulting to the main activity's implementation of the method, regardless of which Activity you specify in tools:context)

Comment: This is weird then. Sounds like a Bug in Android Studio to me. As I'm using AndroidAnnotations @Click annotation to do this kind of binding i did not use thie onClick attribute for a long time now.

Comment: I agree that it's probably just a bug now that I've seen everyone's answers and comments. I hate bloated code editors, so I'm just going to write my code and try to ignore Android Studio's half-baked frills.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will call the method from the activity class of that view. So simply it will call from main activity class if that view is from main activity and if the view is from , for example Activity2, then it will look for the sendMessage method in the Activity2. If it failed to find the sendMessage method in the Activity2 class then it will throw a NullpointerException.